# print System.out.println() result in console

Tags: blackberry

I start the simulator "Debug As > Blackberry Simulator", the debugger is attached and then I see lots of things when the simulator starts. It includes my println statements too. But i want to see my println statements only, then the debuging will be more easier.Any way?

the output i am getting in console is

```
[0.0] JVM: bklt[1] @16945: JvmBacklightEnableFor 30 ()
[0.0] VM:-DA 0
[0.0] VM:+CR
[0.0] VM:-CR=0
[0.0] AM: init
[0.0] VM:PISVt=0,h=2e47,id=e44ef6bca97b83b2
[0.0] JVM: bklt[1] @-805309853: JBSC on=1
[0.0] JVM: bklt[1] @-805309853: SC 1
[0.0] JVM: bklt @17007: setTimer 30
[0.0] AM: Starting tier 0
[0.0] VM:NCICv=36
[0.0] AM: Starting net_rim_crypto
[0.0] AM: Started net_rim_crypto(2)
[0.0] AM: Starting net_rim_tac
[0.0] AM: Started net_rim_tac(3)
[0.0] AM: Starting net_rim_bb_elt
[0.0] VM:NCICv=30
[0.0] VM:NFICv=5
[0.0] VM:NFICv=4
[0.0] VM:NFICv=8
[0.0] VM:NFICv=7
[0.0] VM:NFICv=6
[0.0] AM: Started net_rim_bb_elt(4)
[0.0] AM: Starting net_rim_escreen_app
[0.0] AM: Started net_rim_escreen_app(5)
[0.0] AM: Starting net_rim_tid_spell_check
```

Comment: The alternative here is [to use the EventLogger API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15936395/119114), instead of `println()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to filter out unwanted console messages. But there is a workaround. Add `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!` or something like that to the start of your messages, it will help you to find your messages in the whole heap of console output.

For instance:

```
System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!! myVar: " + myVar);
```