# Strange BlackBerry log

Tags: java, logging, blackberry, push-notification

I am using the code below , as part of my push notifications implementation:

```
private static final String BPAS_URL = "http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com";
private static final String APP_ID = "3582-M4687r9k9k836r980kO2395i32i66y11a34";

String registerUrl = formRegisterRequest(BPAS_URL, APP_ID, null) + ";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public";

System.out.println("\n\n\n !!msg registerBPAS URL is:  "+ registerUrl + "\n\n");
```

where :

```
private static String formRegisterRequest(String bpasUrl, String appId, String token) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(bpasUrl);
    sb.append("/mss/PD_subReg?");
    sb.append("serviceid=").append(appId);
    sb.append("&osversion=").append(DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion());
    sb.append("&model=").append(DeviceInfo.getDeviceName());
    if (token != null && token.length() > 0) {
        sb.append("&").append(token);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

What i get printed is this :

```
!!msg registerBPAS URL is:  http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_subReg?serviceid=3582-M4687r9[0.0] k9k836r980kO2395i32i66y11a34&osversion=5.0.0.669&model=9520;deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-publ[0.0] ic
```

I cant understand why though. Why there are `spaces " "` in the URL and why is there a `"[0.0]"`

From the code above i cant explain this behavior.

What i would expect to be printed is this:

```
!!msg registerBPAS URL is:  http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_subReg?serviceid=3582-M4687r9k9k836r980kO2395i32i66y11a34&osversion=5.0.0.669&model=9520;deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public
```

*I dont have BIS enabled if this is any help , but i dont think it matters as i am forming the URL locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you're seeing is an extra `[0.0]` in your log in a couple places.

**This is normal ... your URL is fine.**

Calling

```
System.out.println("");
```

does not give you *exclusive*, or *atomic*, access to `stdout`.  In other words, while the log is printing out the String you passed to `println()`, you can also get these tokens printed to the log, and other messages from the BlackBerry OS, and they may/will be placed right in the middle of your log output.

It's annoying, but there's nothing wrong with your code.

If you want another option, look at the BlackBerry [EventLogger API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventLogger.html), which writes to a log that you can [pull off the device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6440409/119114), and search through for your messages, without the annoying `[0.0]`.